# Read an XML file in a WCF service and return XML from the service

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to read an XML file in my WCF service and return the same file as XML back from my WCF service in C#. Can someone point me to the right direction. Most samples out there seems outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just return `XmlElement` (for example, the root element) and it'll work?

```
    [OperationContract]
    XmlElement GetXml(string path);

...

    public XmlElement GetXml(string path) {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path); // TODO: add security...
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Comment: is there any well defined way to access the xml file. I have stored it in App_Data folder inside the wcf service. Is there some method i can use to map path `~/App_Data/Data.xml` to it's physical path for reading through Linq to Xml. thanks

Comment: @Deeptechtons are you using ASP.NET compatibility mode? If so, just use Server.MapPath

Comment: no i ain't enabled it. Is there a way round without enabling compatibility mode?

Comment: @Deeptechtons not sure; this question was nearly 3 years ago, and I rarely use WCF these days

Comment: No problem :) I will use it unless a neat way is found. So that do you work on these day if i may ask?

Comment: @Deeptechtons whatever is needed. Here at stackoverflow we simply don't really use WCF.