# How to sign an xml file in a wcf service?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'd like my WCF service to return an xml file that has been signed.

I found documentation that shows how to sign an XmlDocument on msdn, but since a WCF function can't return an XmlDocument I'm not sure if the following would work (similar to this[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905219/read-an-xml-file-in-a-wcf-service-and-return-xml-from-the-service))

```
public XmlElement GetXml() {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        // add data to doc
        // sign doc
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Would it still be possible to verify the signature of doc.DocumentElement if I added it to another XmlDocument after a client requested it? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: a WCF function should be able to return XMLDocument as well, as far as i can tell. Have you tried [OperationContract] 
    XmlDocument GetXml(); ?

Comment: @In Sane - Thanks for your comment. Yeah I have it set up correctly with [OperationContract] in the interface. When I use XmlDocument the WCF test client fails to load with this message "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.", when I use XmlElement as above I can't test the function, but when I use String as the return value it works :). I'm very knew to WCF, so any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlDocument is not decorated with DataContractAttribute and I cannot see why the object needs to be sent over the wire while the serialized form (text form) is all that is required.

I would design it as:

```
[OperationContract]
string GetFooXml();
```

And send the string. That is what WCF/XML is for, sending data as text whenever possible so that more kinds of clients can consume it.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It will be escaped when it is sent so you shouldn't have any problem.